# Entity Framework OrderBy list of dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, how can I select the latest meeting using the `MeetingDateList`?

I tried using the  `.OrderByDescending(y => y.MeetingDateList.Select(x => x.StartDate))` but I get an error.

Error DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.\r\nParameter name: key"}

```
select new Model.Meeting
       {
           MeetingId = i.MeetingId,
           MeetingDateList = (from m in db.MeetingDates
                              where i.MeetingId == m.MeetingId
                              orderby m.MeetingDateId
                              select new Model.MeetingDate
                                     {
                                         MeetingDateId = m.MeetingDateId,
                                         StartDate = m.StartDate.ToString(),
                                         StartTime = m.StartTime.ToString(),
                                     }).ToList(),
       })
       .OrderByDescending(y => y.MeetingDateList.Select(x => x.StartDate))
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Could you give a hint to what the "error" mentioned in the description is please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* you want to order by the latest MeetingDate-StartDate in that list, so use `Max`:

```
.OrderByDescending(y => y.MeetingDateList.Select(x => x.StartDate).Max())
```